# Windows Batch file ELSE errors

Tags: batch-file

I have been working with a section of code trying to get the following to work:

```
echo Date %dayCnt% day(s) before %DBName%_%CurDate% is %DBName%_%mm%_%dd%_%yyyy:~2,2%
rem ============================
If exist %Destination%%DBName%_%CurDate% (
  echo 1
  If exist %Destination%%DBName%_%mm%_%dd%_%yyyy:~2,2% (
  echo 2
    Echo %Destination%%DBName%_%mm%_%dd%_%yyyy:~2,2% exists!
    echo 3
  ) ELSE (
    echo 4
    Echo No %Destination%%DBName%_%mm%_%dd%_%yyyy:~2,2% here today. Maybe we make one?  
    echo 4
  ) ELSE (
    echo 5
    Echo No %Destination%%DBName%_%CurDate% here
    echo 6
))
```

The output I get states:

```
Date 3 day(s) before 31499DB_07_22_13 is 31499DB_07_19_13
ELSE was unexpected at this time.
```

If I drop the `ELSE` ( to the next line, I get something closer to what I want to see. When the code looks like this:

```
echo Date %dayCnt% day(s) before %DBName%_%CurDate% is %DBName%_%mm%_%dd%_%yyyy:~2,2%
rem ============================
rem dir %Destination%%DBName%_%CurDate%
If exist %Destination%%DBName%_%CurDate% (
echo 1
  If exist %Destination%%DBName%_%mm%_%dd%_%yyyy:~2,2% (
  echo 2
    Echo %Destination%%DBName%_%mm%_%dd%_%yyyy:~2,2% exists!
    echo 3
  ) 
  ELSE (
  echo 4
    Echo No %Destination%%DBName%_%mm%_%dd%_%yyyy:~2,2% here today. Maybe we make one?  
    echo 4
) 
ELSE (
echo 5
Echo No %Destination%%DBName%_%CurDate% here
echo 6
))
```

The output looks like this:

```
Date 3 day(s) before 31499DB_07_22_13 is 31499DB_07_19_13
1
2
x:31499DB_07_19_13 exists!
3
'ELSE' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
4
No x:31499DB_07_19_13 here today. Maybe we make one?
4
'ELSE' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
5
No x:31499DB_07_22_13 here
6
'))' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What must I do to get this to run without these errors?

Thanks so much,
Sam

Comment: You have an ELSE following an ELSE which does not make any sense

Comment: Thanks folks for the comments. I am attempting to nest these IF statements, thus tying the second occurring IF with first ELSE with the first occurring ELSE; the first occurring IF corresponds to the second occurring ELSE. BTW, thanks Alex for the reformat of my message. I was attempting to clean that up when your edit popped up :-)

Comment: I found a way around my issue by creating subsequent if/else statements. I took out the nested if statements and I believe I can get things to work this way. Thank again for the assist.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `)`.

```
echo Date %dayCnt% day(s) before %DBName%_%CurDate% is %DBName%_%mm%_%dd%_%yyyy:~2,2%
rem ============================
If exist %Destination%%DBName%_%CurDate% (
    echo 1
    If exist %Destination%%DBName%_%mm%_%dd%_%yyyy:~2,2% (
        echo 2
        Echo %Destination%%DBName%_%mm%_%dd%_%yyyy:~2,2% exists!
        echo 3
    ) ELSE (
        echo 4
        Echo No %Destination%%DBName%_%mm%_%dd%_%yyyy:~2,2% here today. Maybe we make one?  
        echo 4
    )
) ELSE (
    echo 5
    Echo No %Destination%%DBName%_%CurDate% here
    echo 6
)
```